# Table does not expand to 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, width

I am displaying an HTML table in a div when the user clicks on a div. However the table is not 100% width like I set it in CSS. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Heres a plunk
https://plnkr.co/edit/wxXzEsLV0Z3a4AqRr5zB?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .boxscore {
        border: solid 1px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 90%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .time_field {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .scores {
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .scores img, h1{
        display: inline-block;
        margin: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 100px;
    }
    #playerStatsTable {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 10px;
        display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="boxscore" onclick="toggleTable()">
        <div class="time_field">
            <label for="time">7:05 PM</label>
            <label for="field">@PNC Park</label>
        </div>
        <div class="scores">
            <img src="sd.png">
            <h1>5</h1>
            <h1>-</h1>
            <h1>2</h1>
            <img src="pit.png">
        </div>
        <div id="playerstats"></div>
            <table id="playerStatsTable">
                <tr>
                    <th>Player</th>
                    <th>R</th>
                    <th>RBI</th>
                    <th>1B</th>
                    <th>2B</th>
                    <th>3B</th>
                    <th>HR</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                    <th>Player</th>
                    <th>R</th>
                    <th>RBI</th>
                    <th>1B</th>
                    <th>2B</th>
                    <th>3B</th>
                    <th>HR</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>R</td>
                    <td>RBI</td>
                    <td>1B</td>
                    <td>2B</td>
                    <td>3B</td>
                    <td>HR</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var t = 0;

    function toggleTable() {
        if (t == 0) {
            document.getElementById("playerStatsTable").style.display="block";
            t = 1;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("playerStatsTable").style.display="none";
            t = 0;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're displaying a table, so don't set the display to block, set it to table:

```
document.getElementById("playerStatsTable").style.display="table";
```

```js
var t = 0;

function toggleTable() {
  if (t == 0) {
    document.getElementById("playerStatsTable").style.display = "table";
    t = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("playerStatsTable").style.display = "none";
    t = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.container {
  padding: 10px;
}
.boxscore {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.time_field {
  text-align: center;
}
.scores {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.scores img,
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
}
#playerStatsTable {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxscore" onclick="toggleTable()">
    <div class="time_field">
      <label for="time">7:05 PM</label>
      <label for="field">@PNC Park</label>
    </div>
    <div class="scores">
      <img src="sd.png">
      <h1>5</h1>
      <h1>-</h1>
      <h1>2</h1>
      <img src="pit.png">
    </div>
    <div id="playerstats"></div>
    <table id="playerStatsTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Player</th>
        <th>R</th>
        <th>RBI</th>
        <th>1B</th>
        <th>2B</th>
        <th>3B</th>
        <th>HR</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Player</th>
        <th>R</th>
        <th>RBI</th>
        <th>1B</th>
        <th>2B</th>
        <th>3B</th>
        <th>HR</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>RBI</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>2B</td>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>HR</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your plunker and inspected the table element and it is 100% width of its parent element after padding.

If you are trying to get the columns to distribute evenly across the entire width of the table, then add a bit of css to the appropriate selectors: https://plnkr.co/edit/xvtd9zh9bphy47RYxEQg?p=preview

```
#playerStatsTable {
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        display: none;
        overflow: hidden;
}
th, td {
 padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped the formatting of the table